Can't clone git repo due to username being in capital letters
I just got a new computer. Installed git and gerrit as i always do. Now for some reason i can't clone my repos using the functions i previously had. I did some fault tracing and found that the reason for it not working, is because the command puts my username in capital letters.
For example
This command does not work. It will return Permission denied (publickey).
git clone ssh://MYUSERNAME@ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net:29256/xxx/repo


This does
git clone ssh://myusername@ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net:29256/xxx/repo


I have tried to change my username to capital letters and if i run git config --list | grep user.name in Git Bash it returns it with capital letters.
But in my gerrit account it is always in lowercase.
I face the same problem when i try to push into my repo. I can't say for certain that it is the same problem but the line of code it tries to execute also has my username in capital letters.

So why not just checkout the repo using the lowercase username if that's how you're set up in gerrit?

We have a lot of build in code in various functions that use capital letters. It works for everyone in my team except me. Can't go changing those.

Posix usernames are case sensitive, so if this is a posix system, it matters.  Is it just that somebody created all caps usernames on the Garrit side and you broke the pattern and created lowercase usernames on the garrit side?

common gotcha: git config user.name is used to write your user name in the commit messages, and has noting to do with credentials used to pull/push from a remote. The username is probably stored in the remote url: git remote -v

To debug ssh authentication issues, first check that your connection works with a regular ssh client: ssh -v -p 29256 user@server

If everyone is using the same scripts, you can just convert everyone's names to lowercase in the tools:
git clone ssh://${USER,,}@ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net:29256/xxx/repo

In bash 4, the syntax ${x,,} converts the variable x to all lowercase. That works for me in Git Bash.

Since it's an ssh connection,  your ~/.ssh/config file under MacOS/Linux can control the username it sends.
Add an entry for the host to which you are connecting.
host ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net         
     user your_name_but_lowercase
     port 29256

Then you can checkout by omitting your username and port completely
git clone ssh://ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net/xxx/repo

Want to type even less?  Add another entry with a shorthand host:
host ast-gerrit-ssh
     hostname ast-gerrit-ssh.xxxxxx.net         
     user your_name_but_lowercase
     port 29256

Then you can do
git clone ssh://ast-gerrit-ssh/xxx/repo

